# if F is injective it implies that for all X,Y $ \subset $ A : f(X $\cap$ Y) = f(X) $\cap$ f(Y)

Tags: logic

i have this as a homework so please don't provide a full answer but i'm not getting my head around it. i know that i have to prove that i $ \Rightarrow $ ii and ii $ \Rightarrow $ i but i'm not seeing how that it's injective would help.

[image: the homework]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: To see how the two statements are related, consider what might happen if $f$ is not injective, and $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. For instance, if $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is the archetypal non-injective function $f(x) = x^2$, with $X = [-2, -1]$ and $Y = [1, 2]$. Then $X\cap Y = \varnothing$, so $f(X\cap Y) = \varnothing$. However, $f(X) = f(Y) = f(X)\cap f(Y) = [1, 4]$.

Do this exact thing more generally, and you have the implication (ii)$\implies$(i) by virtue of contrapositivity. As for (i)$\implies$(ii), I think that that's easiest to do by using injectivity of $f$ to show $f(X)\cap f(Y)\subseteq f(X\cap Y)$ directly, but you're welcome to try the contrapositive if you like.

Comment: but if your function is in the real numbers then it's not injective anymore because you can get the same value from -2 and 2. Or did i understood wrongly?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji Yes, you did. What I did was demonstrate how "(ii)$\implies$(i)" by way of contrapositivity, namely "not (i)$\implies$not (ii)". These two are equivalent, and some times contrapositivity makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

(ii)$\implies$(i)

What happens if for $X$ and $Y$ you take distinct singletons?

(i)$\implies$(ii)

If $z\in f(X)\cap f(Y)$ then $f(x)=z=f(y)$ for some $x\in X$ and some $y$ in $Y$.

Now apply injectivity in order to prove that $z\in f(X\cap Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $i\Rightarrow ii$ Let $f$ be injective.
 As we see $f(X\cap Y)\subseteq f(X)\cap f(Y)$. Conversely, let $x\in f(X)\cap f(Y)$. Then there exists $x_1\in X$ and $x_2\in Y$ such that $x=f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since $f$ is injective we have $x_1=x_2$. Hence $x\in f(X\cap Y)$.
 You can use this to prove $ii\Rightarrow i$.

Comment: i managed te prove from ii to i but i'm really not understanding how to prove it the other way around.

Comment: Ok.Hint: Let $x_1, x_2\in A$. Let $X=\{x_1\}$ and $Y=\{x_2\}$. If $x_1\neq x_2$, then $ X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Show that $f(X)\cap f(Y)=\emptyset$ and deduce that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, so $f$ is injective.